# How to autocalculate drop down menu selections and show total?

Tags: muse

I have designed a website in Adobe Muse. I have an order form that has options to select an item from a drop down list, which has its own price, and then after all items are selected a total is generated.

Heres the code that i have and just need the calculate section of the code and JavaScript if possible:

```
<form name=myform>
    <select name=mytextarea>
        <option name=one value=one>  </option>
        <option name=two value=two> Standard Digital </option>
        <option name=three value=three> Matte Laminated </option>
    </select>
</form>

<form name=myform>
    <select name=mytextarea>
        <option name=one value=one>  </option>
        <option name=two value=two> 5.5mm x 5.5mm </option>
        <option name=three value=three> 8.5mm x 5.5mm </option>
        <option name=four value=four> 9.0mm x 5.0mm </option>
    </select>
</form>

<form name=myform>
    <select name=mytextarea>
        <option name=one value=one>  </option>
        <option name=two value=two> 125 </option>
        <option name=three value=three> 250 </option>
        <option name=four value=four> 500 </option>
    </select>
</form>

<form name=myform>
    <select name=mytextarea>
        <option name=one value=one>  </option>
        <option name=two value=two> Same Day Collection</option>
        <option name=three value=three> Delivery (+ £10)</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

so for each option i need a price to generate and then after all options have been selected, a total should be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Right my thoughts on this are that you would be better to use PHP to do this and then use an

```
<iframe> </iframe>
```

Place this is Muse from selecting Object > insert HTML

PHP is very good for this and there are plenty of bits you can find online to get it done.

That's what I would do if it was me.

Cheers